# My very simple Jasmine test fails with message 'Expected 0 to be 1.'

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I am beginner of CoffeeScript and Jasmine. I tried to test a simple class as below:

```
class Counter
    count: 0

    constructor: ->
        @count = 0

    increment: ->
        @count++

    decrement: ->
        @count--

    reset: ->
        @count = 0

root = exports ? this
root.Counter = Counter
```

Then, I wrote test code as below:

```
describe("Counter", ->
    counter = new Counter
    it("shold have 0 as a count variable at first", ->
        expect(counter.count).toBe(0)
    )

    describe('increment()', ->
        it("should count up from 0 to 1", ->
            expect(counter.increment()).toBe(1)
        )
    )
)
```

The second test always failed and the message was below:

```
Expected 0 to be 1.
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the pre-increment and pre-decrement forms if you want your `increment` and `decrement` methods to return the updated values:

```
increment: -> ++@count
decrement: -> --@count
```

`x++` yields the value of `x` and then increments `x` so this:

```
return x++
```

is equivalent to:

```
y = x
x = x + 1
return y
```

whereas this:

```
return ++x
```

is like this:

```
x = x + 1
return x
```

So Jasmine is right and has nicely uncovered a bug in your code.

For example, [this code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Counter%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@count%20=%200%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20incr_post%3a%20-%3E%20@count++%0A%20%20%20%20incr_pre%3a%20%20-%3E%20++@count%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%28new%20Counter%29.incr_post%28%29%29%0Aconsole.log%28%28new%20Counter%29.incr_pre%28%29%29):

```
class Counter
    constructor: (@count = 0) ->
    incr_post: -> @count++
    incr_pre:  -> ++@count

c1 = new Counter
c2 = new Counter    

console.log(c1.incr_post())
console.log(c2.incr_pre())
```

will give you `0` and `1` (in that order) in the console even though `@count` will be `1` inside both `c1` and `c2` when you're done.